How to install tar manually in a specific location?
Anyone know how to install tar manually in a specified location? (I did not mean install something from a .tar file. I want to install the tar utility)
Thanks in advance

Install it from where? Why?

I immediately see four different ways:

Download the package deb file and use dpkg-deb -x $DEBFILE $TARGET_DIRECTORY

Install the tar package using apt, copy /usr/bin/tar to the new location, uninstall the package

Download the tar package, extract the contents using ar vx ..., untar the data file into the new location

Download the tar source and build with the install location pointing to your directory


I am assuming that you only want the tar executable for some of these solutions.
